# please explain the error to me, Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, debugging

Iam newbie and now learning to make customize react hooks
here i am trying to call the function i made in app.js file, i want to use it onClick button. but fail to do so. please help me to find the error and understand it.

```js
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react";

const useRandomJoke = () => {
  const [jokes, setJokes] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const jokeFetch = async() => {
      await fetch("https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random")
        //we'll run 2 "then"
        .then(
          // this will give us response and will return inform of res.json
          (res) => res.json()
        ) //.json is a format
        .then((data) => {
          setJokes(data.value.joke);
        }); // now calling data from te returned values in res.json
    };
    jokeFetch();
  }, []);
  return jokes;
};

export default useRandomJoke;
```

```
//With onClick function 

function App() { const [jokes, setJokes] = useState(); 
return (
<div className="App">
  <h1>Random Jokes</h1>
  <p>{jokes}</p>
  <button onClick={()=>{setJokes(useRandomJoke)}}>
     Click for Jokes</button>
</div>
); } export default App;
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useRandomJoke` is a custom hook. Hooks should only be called at the top level of a component and as the custom hook already has the `joke` state, you don't need an additional state in the `App` component.

If you want to get a new joke after the component renders and every time the button gets clicked, you can do this:

```
const useRandomJoke = () => {
  const [joke, setJoke] = useState("");

  const fetchJoke = useCallback(() => {
    fetch("https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setJoke(data.value.joke);
      });
  }, []);

  return [joke, fetchJoke];
};

export default function App() {
  const [joke, fetchJoke] = useRandomJoke();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchJoke();
  }, [fetchJoke]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Random Jokes</h1>
      <p>{joke}</p>
      <button onClick={fetchJoke}>Click for a random joke</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit naughty-bird-fv05i]

Answer (score 1):

You can't conditionally call React hooks, like in the `onClick` handler of the button, as this breaks the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). I suggest refactoring the `useRandomJoke` hook to return the fetched joke ***and*** a function to fetch the next random joke. You also shouldn't mix `async/await` with Promise chains as this is an anti-pattern.

```
const useRandomJoke = () => {
  const [jokes, setJokes] = useState(null);

  const jokeFetch = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random");
    const data = await res.json();
    setJokes(data.value.joke)
  };

  return [jokes, jokeFetch];
};
```

Then use the hook in the app.

```
function App() {
  const [joke, getJoke] = useRandomJoke();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Random Jokes</h1>
      <p>{joke}</p>
      <button onClick={getJoke}>Click for Joke</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit please-explain-the-error-to-me-error-rendered-more-hooks-than-during-the-previ]

Comment: I tried and understood your method. it worked. thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is more than one point to talk about here:

1- in React.js, you can only call custom hooks at the top level of your function's body (react recognizes any function starting with the keyword `use` as a hook)

```
function App() { 
  // top level is here
  
  const randomJokes = useRandomJoke()

  const [jokes, setJokes] = useState(); 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Random Jokes</h1>
      <p>{jokes}</p>
      <button onClick={()=>{setJokes(useRandomJoke)}}>
        Click for Jokes
       </button>
    </div>
); } 
export default App;
```

2- In your example I understand you want to have a new joke each time `onClick` triggers, in order to do so, I don't think using a custom hook is the ideal solution here, since your custom hook runs the `fetchJokes` method only once on initial render (as you described in your `useEffect` hook), I understand a lot of people mention that `useEffect` is the place to make API calls, but it doesn't necessarily applies to all use cases, in your example it is simple, you don't have to use `useEffect` neither create a custom hook.

a possible simple solution:

```
function App() {
  // we always call hooks at the top level of our function
  const [jokes, setJokes] = useState();
  const fetchNewJoke = () => {
  
      fetch("https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random")
        //we'll run 2 "then"
        .then(
          // this will give us response and will return inform of 
           res.json
          (res) => res.json()
        ) //.json is a format
        .then((data) => {
          setJokes(data.value.joke);
        }); // now calling data from te returned values in res.json
    };
};

    return (
     <div className="App">
      <h1>Random Jokes</h1>
      <p>{jokes}</p>
      <button onClick={fetchNewJoke}>Click for Joke</button>
     </div>
    );
} export default App;
```

Comment: I appreciate you for helping me out. actually i was practicing to work on customise hooks.

Comment: Wish you the best on your learning journey!